# How do I properly format the user_role array?

Tags: users, user-roles, array, customization, select

I used a role editor recently and needed to delete a role. After deleting it I noticed that it began to appear as blank in the edit user role drop-down. After a bit of investigating and deleting entries from the database. I renabled more_fields and the blank boxes reappeared. I then did a db search and found multiple entries in wp_options more_fields as

`a:12:{i:0;s:13:"administrator";i:1;s:6:"editor";i:2;s:6:"author";i:3;s:11:"contributor";i:4;s:10:"subscriber";i:5;s:11:"distributor";i:6;s:10:"integrator";i:7;s:5:"sales";i:8;s:7:"support";i:9;s:7:"revisor";i:10;s:7:"premier";i:11;s:9:"marketing";}`

I've tried adjusting it back to wps default roles like the example below but it causes a 404.

`a:5:{i:0;s:13:"administrator";i:1;s:6:"editor";i:2;s:6:"author";i:3;s:11:"contributor";i:4;s:10:"subscriber";}`

Do I have my syntax correct or am I missing something else?

I've added the database entry to pastebin, you'll notice that the user role array is listed five times. Thanks for the help. http://pastebin.com/RpsFytgc

[image]

Comment: Also, a user provided me with this example. Unfortunately, I don't have the original post to provide credit. http://www.seodenver.com/custom-rss-feed-in-wordpress/

Comment: have you tried using WordPress's builtin remove_role function?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_role

Comment: Yeah I think that's what initially caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
a:5:{
s:13:"administrator";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Administrator";s:12:"capabilities";a:54:{s:13:"switch_themes";b:1;s:11:"edit_themes";b:1;s:16:"activate_plugins";b:1;s:12:"edit_plugins";b:1;s:10:"edit_users";b:1;s:10:"edit_files";b:1;s:14:"manage_options";b:1;s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:6:"import";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:8:"level_10";b:1;s:7:"level_9";b:1;s:7:"level_8";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_users";b:1;s:12:"create_users";b:1;s:17:"unfiltered_upload";b:1;s:14:"edit_dashboard";b:1;s:14:"update_plugins";b:1;s:14:"delete_plugins";b:1;s:15:"install_plugins";b:1;s:13:"update_themes";b:1;s:14:"install_themes";b:1;}}
s:6:"editor";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Editor";s:12:"capabilities";a:34:{s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;}}
s:6:"author";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Author";s:12:"capabilities";a:10:{s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;}}
s:11:"contributor";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:11:"Contributor";s:12:"capabilities";a:5:{s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;}}
s:10:"subscriber";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Subscriber";s:12:"capabilities";a:2:{s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;}}}
```

which are the roles and capabilities that are set by default.

Comment: Is this something I'll be able to do to the more_fields db entry? It's significantly different and occurs five times within it. http://pastebin.com/RpsFytgc

Comment: The user role array is WordPress built-in data and not something generated by more fields. Look it up in the options database table.

Comment: Interesting, I was pretty sure the reason I was seeing blank drop downs was because the data was being retained in the more_fields table. If I shut off all of the site's plugins, correct the table data with default data and then re-enable it. It re-applys all of the information back to user_role in wp_options and the role select appears blank.

Comment: I think I now get what you were saying. The problem I was having was More Fields was creating custom roles and overriding WordPress's roles. I fixed this by downloading Justin Tadlock's member's plugin and remade all of the roles. I'm still unable to delete them but its better than an empty dropdown. I read your reference on this post and it clarified what you were saying here. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23054/help-i-screwed-up-my-wp

Comment: Glad to hear you got it.