# Help!! I Screwed up my WP

Tags: plugins, mysql

I was trying to clear up some empty tables left behind by other previously used plugins. As such i was trying to delete the GD Star rating plugin and now I cannot access my WP admin. i get the `'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page'`

I turned on the debug to true and saw the errors caused by lots of plugins. So I disabled all of them, but nothing helps:

This was the query I had run (and then just checked the output and clicked 'Drop' which messed it up.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `mydomain_main`.`wp_options` 
WHERE (
`option_id` LIKE  '%ratings_%'
OR  `blog_id` LIKE  '%ratings_%'
OR  `option_name` LIKE  '%ratings_%'
OR  `option_value` LIKE  '%ratings_%'
OR  `autoload` LIKE  '%ratings_%'
)
```

Can someone please please advise

Comment: open your phpmyadmin or any other database management application you have, and check if you didn't delete the `wp_options` table.

Comment: no, the wp_options table still exists. The front end of the website still works fine. Its just the wp-admin that i'm unable to login to

Comment: Maybe you deleted the roles and capabilities from the database check for an option named `wp_user_roles` and reset it to the default as posted here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17614/how-do-i-properly-format-the-user-role-array/17629#17629

Comment: Tried that. Didn't help. I also disabled all plugins and enabled debug to true. I get the following message

`Notice: Undefined index: page in public_html/wp-content/themes/weekly/functions/theme-options.php on line 444

Notice: Undefined index: in public_html/wp-admin/includes/menu.php on line 219

You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.`

theme-options line 444 has the following code: 
`if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {`

Comment: Bainternet.. YOU SAVED MY LIFE!! It was indeed the wp_user_roles that was deleted. THANKS A TON, You have no idea about the #$$t you saved me from!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since i posted as a comment and most people miss the good tips that are in the comments, I'm posting again as an answer

The reason is because `GD Star rating` plugin creates custom capabilities and your query deleted all references of `%rating%` it deleted the `wp_user_roles` option which holds all capabilities roles.

the solution would be to re create that option in options table (usually wp_options) with the default value just like I answered [**here**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17614/how-do-i-properly-format-the-user-role-array/17629#17629)
.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to hear this, but I would suggest to reinstall WordPress and put your backups back. In the end that would be the fastest, easiest and most 'secure' = as in making sure you're not forgetting something which might cause issues in the future.